# Of what type is the return value of get_index?

Tags: multi-index

Every single example out there that shows how to use a secondary index in the EOSIO platform, including the scant documentation on the function found here: https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/latest/group__multiindex/#function-get_index,  declares its value locally using the keyword `auto`, like this:

```
void myaction() {
    ...
    auto zip_index = addresses.get_index<name("zip")>();
```

As I don't need to initialise this value in every method where I use it, I'd like to declare it in my contract class and initialise it in the constructor.  However, I cannot declare it in the class using `auto`:

> /Users/ekkis/dev/eos/dapp.cpp:39:5: error: 'auto' not allowed
>   in non-static class member
>       auto idxtst;

can anyone tell me how to properly declare the correct type?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question that is 2 months old already but still unanswered, so I thought I could reply to it for record, since it had quite a few visualisations...

Actually the function `get_index<IndexName>()` is a template function and depending on the template argument that specifies the index you want to get, then a specific type can be returned.

It will return a `multi_index::index` object, which is a private wrapper struct type for a `multi_index`, so it is not accessible outside of the `multi_index` namespace.

So the short answer is that you can't declare a member to hold an `multi_index::index`, since it's type isn't available outside of `multi_index` namespace, so only `get_index<...>()` is capable of returning those.